# How does react look at the rendering aspect when the order of items in a list is changed and unique key is used as index for them?

Tags: reactjs

I learnt that while rendering list items react looks at their keys have changed or not from previous render and accordingly it only re-renders only the changed item. This way it saves rendering time and gives performance benefit in case of a long list and complex application.

I have an example where I have 3 items in a list with unique keys.
I am just changing their order of appearance in the list.
How does the rendering logic work in this case. Because I am rendering the same number of elements with same value and same key. Practically there is no change in the items key value since they are unique.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const colors = [
  { id: '1abc', name: 'Green' },

  { id: '2pqr', name: 'Blue' },
  { id: '3xyz', name: 'Red' },

];

function ListItems() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {colors.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Next time, lets say I change the colors array to this with 2nd and 3rd elements exchanged:

```
 const colors = [
  { id: '1abc', name: 'Green' },
  { id: '3xyz', name: 'Red' },
  { id: '2pqr', name: 'Blue' },

 ];
```

How does the rendering logic work in this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keys for each element have remained same, only you have re-ordered.
React uses keys to determine which elements have changed and need to re-render.

It will just re-order the DOM element according to match of new order of items in the array, instead of re-rendering them.

To understand the inner working of React ->

1. It diffs the old and new list
2. It sees the keys are all the same, but in a different order.
3. It re-orders the DOM nodes, without any re-rendering.

Checkout [this](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-a-form-with-a-key) example of [react.dev](https://react.dev/) and solve the `swap two form fields` challenge of the same article to better understand this concept.